# MongoDB: Custom Port & DB Path Not Working

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have a new MongoDB server that I want to run with a custom port + db path.

I made these edit in my /etc/mongod.conf:

`port = 53214
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`

I can confirm the `dbpath` exists and is owned by the mongodb user.

But, when I try to start mongod (`service mongod start`), it wants to use port `27017` and dbpath `/data/db`.

I tried deleting `mongod.lock` in `/var/lib/mongodb`, but that didn't help.

My question:

Do I have to manually pass these parameters each time I start mongod?

`mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --port 53214`

If so, what's the point of the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you need to pass in the config file, like this:

`mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: -f can also be used, as a short alias for --config

Comment: See documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/